# How to import other person's package?

Tags: import

```
import CtCILibrary.*;
public class RotateMatrix {
    public static boolean rotate (int [][]matrix) {
        if ( matrix.length == 0 || matrix.length != matrix[0].length) {
            return false;
        }
        int n = matrix.length;
        for ( int layer = 0 ; layer < n / 2 ; layer++ ) {
            int first = layer;
            int last = n - 1 - first;
            for ( int i = first ; i < last; i++ ) {
                int offset = i - first;
                int top = matrix[first][i];
                //left-> top
                matrix[first][i] = matrix [last-offset][first];
                //bottom -> left
                matrix[last-offset][first] = matrix [last][last-offset];
                //right -> bottom
                matrix[last][last-offset]= matrix[i][last];
                //top->right
                matrix[i][last]=top;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Hi there, I'm trying to import the CtCI library to solve the problem but there's an error message. And from her GitHub, that was how she imported this class. I know we can import the class from java built-in library. But I'm not sure how import works when trying to import from someone else. Could someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing serious programming for a long term app, and by **import** you refer to libraries/dependencies, I highly recommend you using **maven** for it.
If you don't  use maven yet, you can just add the .jar files from you IDE to your project path, but with maven is way better.

If you mean importing a `.java` file written  by someone else, to use part of it in your code, just put the file at your project path, you probably need to adapt  its libraries and imports, and once ready you can just use its methods ans stuff. Just make sure you have tipped at the top of your current file the import sentence of that file.

Comment: Thanks, man. But what did you mean by putting the file at my project path? Like copy and paste the code, then put it into my own package, then import from there?

Comment: @Hank I don't know wich IDE do you use, but you may notice that in almost any project there are some Java files created, in you can check easily the location of you project. You may find packages as well if you created them. By putting the file inside your project path, I mean just put the file among the ones you've already created, kn the same folder, for example. Then you can easily use its content by just writing and import statement '''import yourNameFile'''